# Razor layout component not rendering when using Razor components outside MVC

Tags: .net, razor

I'm building an .NET console app. This is not a web application. I'm trying to use a new feature in .NET 8 for rendering Razor components outside of MVC as mentioned in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-components-outside-of-aspnetcore?preserve-view=true&view=aspnetcore-8.0

I followed all of the instructions here. Everything works fine. Next, I tried adding a basic layout component and have the original component use the layout. Here is the code for both components:

Documents.razor

```
@layout Email

<h1>Render Message</h1>
<p>@Message</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Email.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div>@Body</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the program the rendered output is `<h1>Render Message</h1><p>Hello from the Render Message component!</p>` without any of the layout content. Why is the layout not rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. New code is:

Documents.razor:

```
<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Email)">
    <h1>Render Message</h1>
    <p>@Message</p>
</LayoutView>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Email.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div>@Body</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also created a _Imports.razor file with this code:

```
@using Components.Layout
```

The code is all inside a Components folder. In the Components folder there is a Layout folder. Email.razor is inside that folder. All other files are in the Components folder.

Hope this helps someone in the future.